# Escape and Apostrophe set on a JSON passed thru rails to JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm having some troubles to escape and apostrophe set on a JSON array.
I Have this:

```
@option_change = OptionChange.new(@product).to_json.html_safe
```

On the JS file i use it on this way:

```
var json_test = $.parseJSON('<%= @option_change %>');
```

When this js is executed this is the return:(this is the content of my @option_change)

```
'"[{"option":1,"properties":[{"sequence":null,"option_value":{"id":3,"value":"Test'WithError","image_uid":null,"image_name":null,"description":""},"product_sku_id":82,"available_stock":true}],"next_option":null}]"'
```

I got an error because of the apostrophe set on Test'WithError, i tried using gsub.("'", "\\'") like suggested on another posts, but i think that my issue need a much more specific way to be solved.

@product:`#<Product id: 48, name: "[ADENA][TESTE] 365b4ea2f838", resume: "365b4ea2f838", description: "<p>\r\n\t365b4ea2f838</p>\r\n", created_at: "2017-06-14 21:29:05", updated_at: "2017-06-20 13:10:58", category_id: 1, highlight: 0, highlight_image: nil, category_highlight: false, meta_description_deprecate: nil, meta_keywords_deprecate: nil, seo_title_deprecate: nil, custom_title_deprecate: nil, brand_id: nil, profile_property_id: nil, video_url: "", creditcard_split_config_id: nil, code: nil, product_type_id: 1, unpackable: false, ensemble: false, quantity_uses_decimal: false, minimum_to_buy: #<BigDecimal:7f93ee2f7f90,'0.1E1',9(18)>, delta: true, availability: true, visits: 73, additions: 0, removals: 0, custom_delivery_time_deprecated: nil, sales: nil, google_shopping_identifier_exists: true, private: false, keywords: "", extends_delivery_type: "minute", extends_delivery_time: nil>`

You guys have any idea how to?

Thanks!

Comment: try gsub("'", "\\\\'")

Comment: Tried it already, inside the JSON he consider the apostrophe as the end of the JSON file not as a part of the string.

Comment: What's the value for `@product`?

Comment: is to long to place here. will edit the post with it.

Comment: There should be no need to stringify and then deserialize it. Just do `var json_test  = <%= @option_change %>);` to assign it to the JSON representation directly. `html_safe` may cause problems, too, as this is JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: It still brake the JSON at the apostrophe on Test'WithError.
`[{"option":1,"properties":[{"sequence":null,"option_value":{"id":3,"value":"Test'WithError","image_uid":null,"image_name":null,"description":""},"product_sku_id":82,"available_stock":true}],"next_option":null}]`

Comment: Try `OptionChange.new(@product).as_json`

Comment: When i do without the `html_safe` it send every special character as hexadecimal.
`[{&quot;option&quot;:1,&quot;properties&quot;:[{&quot;sequence&quot;:null,&quot;option_value&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:3,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Teste&#x27;ComErro&quot;,&quot;image_uid&quot;:null,&quot;image_name&quot;:null,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;product_sku_id&quot;:82,&quot;available_stock&quot;:true}],&quot;next_option&quot;:null}]`

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes have no special meaning in JSON so `to_json` will not escape them. For example:

```
> puts "'".to_json
"'"
```

Also note that `to_json` includes the outer quotes in a string so things like this:

```
'<%= some_string.to_json %>'
```

will wrap the double quoted JSON string in single quotes and you'll end up with confusion like:

```
'"{\"k\":\"v\"}"'
'"{\"k\":\"'\"}"'
// --------^ broken string due to an un-escaped inner quote
```

when you really want:

```
"{\"k\":\"v\"}"
"{\"k\":\"'\"}"
// -------^ Not broken as there are no outer single quotes to fight with
```

Consider these results in JavaScript:

```
> JSON.parse("{\"k\":\"v\"}")
< {k: "v"}

> JSON.parse('"{\"k\":\"v\"}"')
< SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string
```

The first one is what you're presumably after.

I think you just want to drop the extra quotes:

```
var json_test = $.parseJSON(<%= @option_change %>);
```

Or better (IMO) push the encoding into the view so that your Ruby says:

```
@option_change = OptionChange.new(@product)
```

and your view says:

```
var json_test = $.parseJSON(<%= @option_change.to_json.html_safe %>);
```

or

```
var json_test = $.parseJSON(<%= @option_change.to_json %>);
```

depending on context.

Comment: I understood about the single quote problem and followed your instructions, anyway it broke.
That was the result anyway:
`var json_test = $.parseJSON([{"option":1,"properties":[{"sequence":null,"option_value":{"id":3,"value":"Test'WithError","image_uid":null,"image_name":null,"description":""},"product_sku_id":82,"available_stock":true}],"next_option":null}]);`
Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @FelipePin did you remove the surrounding quotes as mentioned? I cannot reproduce the issue [Repl.it Example](https://repl.it/IuLs/1)

Comment: @FelipePin however it is very reproducible with the outer quotes [Repl.it](https://repl.it/IuLs/2)

Comment: Yes, i removed the quotes. 
Found an strange fact, when saving the information "Test'WithError" i tried using the ASCII code for the apostrophe (&#39;) like this => "Test&#39;WithError"... without changing anything it worked perfectly.

Comment: So `@option_change` is a Hash in Ruby? If so, then you should be able to skip the `$.parseJSON` stuff and go with something closer to `var json_test = <%= @option_change.to_json %>;`. Or wrap it in double quotes and parse it with `$.parseJSON`.